# Fixed: Loading NHibernate mappings from external assembly leads to exception

Tags: c#, nhibernate, reflection, mapping, .net-assembly

I have searched for existing topics, of course, and tried the solutions presented in them, but without success. Maybe someone can give some additional hints.

Here is the scenario:

I am going to use one NHibernate project for handling entities from several assemblies. The assembly that shall be handled contains some entities as well as mapping files compiled as embedded resources:

```
namespace projectName.namespace
{
    public class Entity
    {
        public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
        public virtual string IsoCode { get; set; }
    }
}

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
    <class name="projectName.namespace.Entity,projectName">
        <id name="Id" column="EntityId">
          <generator class="guid" />
        </id>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

In the NHibernate project then the assembly is loaded via:

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.Load(assemblySourcePath);
```

And finally when adding the mappings to the configuration NHibernate throws an MappingException:

```
configuration.AddAssembly(assembly);
```

I really have no idea how to solve that problem. Does anyone of you?

Regards!

Edit 1
Here is the exception output (translated and summarised):

```
NHibernate.MappingException: Could not compile the mapping document (the one from above)
persistent class "classname, assemblyname" not found -> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: file or assembly "assemblyname" or one of its dependencies not found.
```

Edit 2
I had another try with Fluent NHibernate. The mapping classes get found again, but not the entities:

```
persistent class dom.Project.BusinessEntities.Class, dom.Project, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null not found
```

Regards

Edit 3 Solution
I finally made it, guys. The solution is quite simple and shows that nhibernate can load any assembly, no matter if under the domain root or not.
Install the assembly that shall be loaded to the global assembly cache and nhibernate will stop its protest :-)

Regards and thanks again

Comment: It is always helpful to post the full exception.  Exception.ToString() is your friend.

Comment: My bad, Cole, you are right, of course.. just a second

Comment: What confuses me is that hibernate first finds the mapping files within the assembly but then does not find the assembly itself. Where does nhibernate search for the assembly? Do I have to change the assembly-link in the mapping document?

Comment: Thanks--adding the library to the GAC fixed my issue as well.

Answer (score 0):

Nhibernate can only load entities from the assembly that is located under current app domain root path. Try putting the assembly inside a temporary folder below your bin/Debug and point to it - should solve the problem

Comment: I have tried that, but still does not work, although the codebase of the assembly now is within the debug directory of the nhibernate project. What about the namespaces? I mean could it be a problem, that the one of the nhibernate project (nihbernateproject.dataaccess) differs from namespace.of.otherproject?

Comment: It's not - the assembly cache was the problem respectively its solution.